# Is it normal to throw exception from asynchronous methods?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have some code that I want to refactor (extract server communication methods from controller to separate service).

*Example:*

```
$http.post("/mypath", someData)
    .success(function(request) {
        if (request.ok) {
            $scope.error = "";
            _refreshAppointments();
        }
        else {
            $scope.error = request.err;
        }
    })
    .error(function() {
        $scope.error = "Error during communicating to server";
    });
```

My current problem is errors processing (communication with old $scope). So I want to throw the exceptions instead such lines `$scope.error = "Error during communicating to server";`
And catch them in controller.

Is it good idea?

Comment: We use angular's $resource instead of $http in services and then our success/error callbacks are done in our controllers.

Answer (score 3):

If you throw an error in a vanilla environment:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    throw new Error();
}, 1);
```

The error just gets lost. (`window.onerror` will see it though)

Even if you do:

```
try {
    setTimeout(function () {
        throw new Error();
    }, 1);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

You wont see the error.

You need to wrap each asynchronous event, like:

```
function mySetTimeout(callback, ms) {
    setTimeout(wrap_in_try_catch(callback), ms);
}

mySetTimeout(function () {
    throw new Error();
});
```

You can now catch the error in a generic error handler, but you still can't catch it in the surrounding code.

This is where Promises come in. Not all libraries do Promises the same way (or correctly) so I don't know how good your library support is.

Roughly your code will look like:

```
$.ajax().then(function () {
    throw new Error();
}).fail(e) {
    console.log("it failed!", e);
});
```

If instead you have:

```
$.ajax().then(function () {
    throw new Error();
}); // throws something like: no fail callback for rejected value error
```

Then your global error handler will pick it up. This ensures no error can slip through the cracks and get lost.

Getting a Promise library to work with Errors in this way is not impossible but it's a little bit tricky to set up. Once you have this though, you're good. Error handling becomes a breeze.

You'll never write a try-catch again, just a bunch of `.fail()` handlers.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely good idea to extract REST/http requests into model/service layer and use those services from controller. Then handling failed operation would mean rejecting a corresponding promise, in this case throwing exception in promise effectively means the same.

For example this is how your service/factory could look like:

```
app.factory('dataService', function($http) {
    return {
        load: function() {
            return $http.post("/mypath", someData).then(function(response) {
                if (!response.data.ok) {
                    return throw new Error(response.request.err);
                    // or return $q.reject(response.request.err);
                }
                return response.request;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and consuming controller would deal with promise status, resolved (success) or rejected (failed/exception):

```
dataService.load().then(function(request) {
    $scope.error = "";
    _refreshAppointments();
})
.catch(function(err) {
    $scope.error = err || "Error during communicating to server";
});
```